# Does FILLO support java 16? If not what are the similar alternatives with which we can query an excel

Tags: java, excel

I was using FILLO with Java 8 and after migration to Java 16, FILLO related code stopped working. Is there any alternative for fillo, to query an excel?

Comment: I think fillo is the external jar. check with java16 compatible version

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"?